# Non-invocable member cannot be used like a method?

Tags: c#

I keep getting the following errors in my program:

> 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox.Text' is a 'property' but used like a 'method'

and

> Non-invocable member 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.Text' cannot be used like a method.

Here is the code:

```
if (OffenceBox.Text != "")
   {
 AddBook(int.Parse(AgeBox.Text), NameBox.Text, AddressBox.Text, (HeightBox.Text), OffenceBox.Text());
   }
   else
   {
   MessageBox.Show("Age must be max 3 numbers in length");
   }
   }
```

How can I fix this problem?

EDIT:
Fixed the error and now encountered another:
`Argument 4: Cannot convert String to int` and I can't seem to fix the problem.

Comment: I faced the same error when I upgraded some NuGet packages in a C# project. The error was for `System.Diagnostics.Trace` method. I had to change it to `Trace.TraceInformation` to fix the compilation issue. This error started coming while referring to `System` DLL  v4.0.0.0 which is part of .NET Framework Class Library (FCL).

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Where you've written "OffenceBox.Text()", you need to replace this with "OffenceBox.Text". It's a property, not a method - the clue's in the error!

Comment: This worked but I have encountered another problem where `Argument 4: Cannot convert String to int` and I can't seem to fix it.

Comment: int.Parse(HeightBox.Text) instead of (HeightBox.Text). The Text property is of type string so you need to try to convert it to an int, exactly like you did for AgeBox.Text. Box of these might not be convertible to int though so you need to catch the resulting Exception.

Answer (score 9):

It have happened because you are trying to use the property "OffenceBox.Text" like a method. Try to remove parenteses from `OffenceBox.Text()` and it'll work fine.

Remember that you cannot create a method and a property with the same name in a class.

---

By the way, some alias could confuse you, since sometimes it's method or property, e.g: "Count" alias:

Namespace: System.Linq

```
using System.Linq

namespace Teste
{
    public class TestLinq
    {
        public return Foo()
        {
            var listX = new List<int>();
            return listX.Count(x => x.Id == 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Namespace: System.Collections.Generic

```
using System.Collections.Generic

namespace Teste
{
    public class TestList
    {
        public int Foo()
        {
            var listX = new List<int>();
            return listX.Count;
        }
    }
}
```

---

- Source - Linq: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb338038(v=vs.100).aspx
- Source - List:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/27b47ht3(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 4):

As the error clearly states, `OffenceBox.Text()` is not a function and therefore doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 4):

If you've reached this answer it's because none of the answers above apply to your situation. After all, you are trying to instantiate a class, not use a property. The problem is that you forgot or accidentally deleted the "new" keyword.

```
var obj = YourClass(); // Will throw the non-invocable error.
var obj = new YourClass(); // shhh, it's our secret. We can pretend this never happened.
```

Comment: Coming from Swift, this has happened to me a dozen times already and I can't remember why

Answer (score 1):

For people coming from Google, this error can also arise if you're invoking a generic method but have forgotten one or more of the closing triangular brackets. E.g:

```
// Example 1
var myVar = GetSomeData<AClass();
// Example 2
var myVar2 = GetSomeOtherData<BClass<CClass>();
```

This is easy to spot when you don't have many generics in your method but gets harder the more nesting you've got.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and realized that removing the parentheses worked.
Sometimes having someone else read your code can be useful if you have been the only one working on it for some time.

E.g.

```
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text();
```

Replace:
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

Answer (score 0):

In my context, I faced this error while calling **Count()**

the solution was to **import LINQ**

```
using System.Linq;
```