# C# Non-invocable member cannot be used like a method

Tags: c#, wpf, methods, int

EDIT: For anyone else whom this might help. I did a few things wrong here, some were out of pure laziness.

1. I did not reference the correct method. selectDeviceButton_Click was what I meant to call, that was a silly typo.
2. That method's access modifier should be set to public and not private.
3. I had two arguments in the method, which I couldn't meet.

Perusing the 'similar' questions in StackOverflow has yet to yield any helpful information. So I'm posting my own code and set of problems.

What I'm trying to do is this: A WPF window has a list of audio devices on the current system for you to choose from (check), upon selecting one and pressing the 'select' button - the chosen device's INDEX is sent to another class(this is what I need help with.)

I tried sending the device number, or 'device index' by having my event return it. This code snippet is for my 'device selection' window:

```
private int selectDeviceButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       //Gets the index of the selected item and stores it inside the deviceNumber field.
        int deviceNumber = sourceList.SelectedItems.IndexOf(sourceList.SelectedItem);

       //Hide this window. 
        Hide();

        return deviceNumber;
    }
```

So far so good. Now moving on to my other class, I attempt to get the returned integer.

```
 private void recordButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();
        int devNumb = mw.selectDeviceButton();

    }
```

This class inherits from the other window. I get the error message shown in the title. Was wondering why?

Comment: You've declared a method called `selectDeviceButton_Click` but you appear to be trying to call `selectDeviceButton`... oh, and you're also not providing any arguments to the method, which has two parameters.

Comment: To add on what john said. I am 99.99% sure you did not intend to make a new `MainWindow` and you actually want to use the existing `MainWindow` and want the value from that.

Comment: I took into account everything you guys have said so that the code looks like this: MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();
            int devNumb = mw.selectDeviceButton_Click();                                               No errors now :)

Comment: Related post - [Non-invocable member cannot be used like a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18135758/465053)

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to invoke something that's not actually a method.  `selectDeviceButton` isn't a method, but you're trying to invoke it as if it was a method.  You haven't showed what it is, but given the name, it's probably a button.

Comment: It is a button. Hm. I thought it was a subscriber method?