# Non Invocable Member 'TalesOfMyroth()' can't be used like a method

Tags: c#

```
namespace Tales_Of_Myroth
{
    public class TalesOfMyroth
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TalesOfMyroth();  //here is my error
        }

        private Jogador _jogador;

        public TalesOfMyroth()
        {
            _jogador = new Jogador();

            _jogador.VidaAtual = 50;
            _jogador.VidaMaxima = 50;
            _jogador.Ouro = 0;

            Console.WriteLine("Vida: " + _jogador.VidaAtual);

        }
    }
}
```

I was suppose to make a simple text game for my College that I've just started...could someone help me with this? (Somethings at the code were writen in portuguese)

Comment: Related post - [Non-invocable member cannot be used like a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18135758/465053)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TalesOfMyroth is a `Class` name. so you should use it as a class.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TalesOfMyroth Tales = new TalesOfMyroth();
    }
```

It also good, if you separate the `Main class` and the `Class` for your program. So you would have 2 cs file. 1 is for your `Main Class` and another is for your `TalesOfMyroth class`. Then put those 2 files under the same `namespace`.

if you want to just call a `function`, then you should add `void` into your `function`, with a different name with your `class name`

```
namespace Tales_Of_Myroth
{
    public class TalesOfMyroth
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Tales();
        }

        static private Jogador _jogador;

        public static void Tales()
        {
            _jogador = new Jogador();

            _jogador.VidaAtual = 50;
            _jogador.VidaMaxima = 50;
            _jogador.Ouro = 0;

            Console.WriteLine("Vida: " + _jogador.VidaAtual);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Still you cannot access `Tales` from `main`. Do you know why?

Comment: @un-lucky forgot added `static`. Thx

Answer (score 0):

The `TalesOfMyroth` is a class here, and hence `public void Tales()` will be the constructor of the class. As per the [policies of constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ace5hbzh.aspx), you are not allowed to call it explicitly. It will automatically called when the object of the corresponding class is created.

What you can do in this screen to get out of the error is , Make it as a method by giving a return value(constructor will not return a value, then it will be treated as a method). But you are not supposed to access a non-static method inside a static main. So you need to make it as static method( need to change _jogador as static as well). So the method will become:

```
public static void TalesOfMyroth()
{
   // Code here
}
```

Then you can access the method from `main` as like what you are doing.

Another way to remove this error is : Create an instance of the class in main. then `TalesOfMyroth` will called automatically.