# Error CS1955 Non-invocable member 'MessageModel.Welcome' cannot be used like a method

Tags: asp.net

I have Created Model and named to it: MessageModel.cs
Then my code in this model like this:

```
namespace helloworld.Models
{
    public class MessageModel
    {
        public string Welcome { set; get; }
    }
}
```

After that i skip to my controller to edit this.
Code in Controller:

```
namespace helloworld.Controllers {
    public class Home1Controller : Controller
    {

        public ActionResult Index1()
        {
            var message = new MessageModel();
            message.Welcome ("Hello everyone!");
            return View(message);
        }
    }
}
```

I have type too using helloworld.Models in Home1Controller.cs and using helloword.Controllers in MessageModel.cs but it not work.
I am a newbie and this is first time i have learn asp.net. Thanks you for reading! Have a nice day.

Comment: `message.Welcome` is a property, not a function. You can call it like `message.Welcome = "Hello everyone!";`

Comment: @shahkalpesh Oh it 's work. thanks you very much. Have a nice day

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Non-invocable member cannot be used like a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18135758/non-invocable-member-cannot-be-used-like-a-method)